# brew start an older version of mysql service, but how to connect to it?

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

So I installed `mysql` through `brew`, and I installed 2 versions on my Mac OS -

`mysql 5.7`

`mysql 8.0`

I `brew link` 'ed to 5.7, so if I type `mysql --version`, it gives me `distro 5.7.26`.

The problem is here. Right now if I type `brew services list`, there are
two services `mysql stopped` and `mysql@5.7 stopped`

[image]

If I `brew services start mysql`, then I `sudo mysql` in the Terminal, I can connect to mysql server. But it shows the server instance is `8.0`. Well, I guess unlike command line, `brew services start XXX` would not pick up the linked `XXX`

If I `brew services start mysql@5.7`, and I `sudo mysql`, it would not connect successfully. It gives me the error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` I think it means the mysql client does not find an active open instance.

How to connect to an older version of local mysql instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, resolved myself after 2 days effort.

The solution is that, if I want to run a local `mysql 5.7` instance, I need to completely remove any system `mysql 8.0` . and `mysql 5.7` folder, as well as remove formulas from `brew`

Finally reinstall only `mysql 5.7`.

First uninstall all versions.

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew uninstall mysql@5.7
```

Then remove remaining detritus.

For intel:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql
rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf
```

Alternatively for Apple Silicon:

```
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/
rm /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```

Then reinstall, link, and start the service.

```
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
brew services start mysql@5.7
```

Additionally, on Apple Silicon, if you get an error like this:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

when connecting with `mysql -uroot` to the just started server, try using MySQL's packaged server start tool:

```
brew services stop mysql@5.7
mysql.server start
mysql -uroot
```

as found in https://medium.com/@at0dd/install-mysql-5-7-on-mac-os-mojave-cd07ec936034

Comment: Just want to say thank you for including your own answer! Saved me some time, appreciate the solution